# Return to view after post request without post data

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form which after it submits on a different view and then returns to another view

using `return view("my-view);` after processing my form data.

But the problem is, this still maintains the post data therefore on pressing F5 or refresh form tries to resubmit again.

I know if I redirect to a URL this won't be a problem.

The issue is I don't want to redirect because I want to maintain the same URL.

Please let me know if there is a workaround

Thus if I can return to view and kill the post data or redirect and maintain the same URL.

Thank you.

Comment: then redirect to the same page.

Comment: Its not the same view. The view where the initial form is submitted is different from the view I want to display after form submits

Comment: I think you can use same url for different controller or method. maybe have the one for the form post a `POST` and a different `GET` route for your new view.

More like your url stays same but the request method will be changed.

Comment: @Ghostff This approach wont work because the page to submit the post request loads initially with get request. So I can't have the other view to be displayed when I Want to redirect to the same URL. It will send me back to the same page since thats the main get request

Comment: How abt savings a token in Cookie or session. The refresh the view and serve content if session is there or not?

Comment: Because i don't think laravel have a legit way around this

Comment: Thank @Ghostff I will fall back to redirect to different page.

Comment: Store the first view post data in session and than redirect to same page with view